# Can I use a Google Drive download URL to stream unprocessed video?

Tags: google-drive, video-streaming

How can I use the download feature on Drive to stream an unprocessed video through VLC or another video player?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Google deprecated [this](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html) feature August 2016. Or rather its available only in Google Cloud platform plan, no longer a feature of Google drive.

> As they want to focus on their core user experience.